# install Pig package

Tags: apache, hadoop, debian, ubuntu-11.04

I have to install Hadoop before installing Pig package.
Hadoop requires a working Java 1.6.x installation.So I tried to run the following command to install sun-java6-jdk:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

but I have problems and I obtain this error when trying to install any other package

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in
> simulate
> trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in
> _simulate_helper
> return depends, self._cache.required_download, \   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in
> required_download
> pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records) SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the sun-java6-bin package. This
> might mean you need to manually fix this package.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably it wants you to have hadoop installed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably means that you have not (correctly) installed Hadoop, which is required for running Pig.

You can either install on a single node for testing / development and then deploy on a cluster if you have access to one.

Guide to install Hadoop (either single or cluster):

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html